# what does いずる mean?

Tags: verbs, compound-verbs

what does "いずる (izuru)" mean when it's combined with verbs such as "萌えいずる" ?

Can I say "Sprouting" as a translation of "萌えいずる" ?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Would either of these answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13973/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1303/9831

Comment: One says: "(This 出ずる is in fact a newer spelling of the 連体形 of the 下二段活用動詞「出づ」, 「出づる」, meaning that this sentence fits the bill.)"

And the other says: 

"In Classical Japanese, there is a verb 出いづ which means to go outside of some place or to appear. The conjugation type of this verb is 下二段活用, and it would have become 出いでる in the modern Japanese if it had followed the regular pattern, in the same way as 投なぐ became 投なげる. お出いで is the 連用形れんようけい form of 出でる with the prefix お"

So, I guess "萌えいずる" means the appearing/sprouting of the buds, according to this info.

Answer (score 2):

This いずる is the attributive form of the verb 出ず【いず】 (or 出づ【いづ】 in classical kana orthography), which is basically a classical version of 出る ("to go out", "to appear", etc.). You specified no context but "sprouting" should be fine most of the time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I saw it on a kimono design, where it said "萌えいずる".